# How to do text analysis in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-mllib

I'm quite familiar with Hadoop but totally new to Apache Spark. Currently I'm using LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm implemented in Mahout to do topic discovery. However as I need to make the process faster I'd like to use spark, however the LDA (or CVB) algorithm is not implemented in Spark MLib. Does this mean that I have to implement it from scratch by myself? If so, does Spark provide some tools that make it easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDA has been added to Spark very recently. It is not part of the current 1.2.1 release.

Yet, you can find an example on the current SNAPSHOT version: [LDAExample.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala)

You can also read interesting information about the [SPARK-1405 issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1405).

---

### So how can I use it?

The simplest way while it is not released is probably to copy the following classes in your project, as if you coded them yourself:

- [LDA.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/LDA.scala)
- [LDAModel.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/LDAModel.scala)

Comment: Thanks. So if it's not part of the current release (1.2.1), how come I can use it?

Comment: Thanks, but the Java classes have not been written yet?

Comment: The LDA is officially published in Spark 1.3, however the example on the documentation assume that the documents have already been vectorized. How can we get the actual txt files and make them into vectorized format using Spark to feed to the LDA ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually Spark 1.3.0 is out now so LDA is available !!

c.f. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1405

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Regarding how to use the new Spark LDA API in 1.3:

Here is an article describing the new API:[Topic modeling with LDA: MLlib meets GraphX](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/25/topic-modeling-with-lda-mllib-meets-graphx.html)

And, it links to example code showing how to vectorize text input: [Github LDA Example](https://gist.github.com/jkbradley/ab8ae22a8282b2c8ce33)